# Did Goosebumps 2 have a reference to the Halloween 2018 movie?

Tags: reference, halloween-2018, goosebumps-2

I went to see the Goosebumps 2 movie yesterday and I could swear I saw brief shots of two actors featured in the Halloween movie also playing in theaters, which I saw the previous weekend.

During a scene where Sarah (the sister of the main character) was in her room prior to leaving for a concert, her phone beeped and she unlocked it.  An app similar to Instagram appeared and she saw two images.

The first I swear was the boyfriend of the youngest member of the Strode family (Jamie Lee Curtis' granddaughter).

The second was a group picture but the left side, in the background, looked like a friend of the boyfriend (in the first picture) whose name was Oscar in Halloween movie.

Did the movie makers throw this into the movie as a joke?  (Teens all must know each other on social media)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actor in *Halloween 2018* playing Oscar is [Drew Scheied](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm5902264/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t14) and yes, he appears in *Goosebumps 2* also.